# Изменение типа обобщения

Tags: java

```
ArrayList<Type1> like = new ArrayList();
...
like = ArrayList<Type2>();
```

У меня это не получается. В документации написано, что такая операция недопустима. Можно ли как-то это обойти?

Comment: Как между собой связаны `Type1` и `Type2`?

Comment: Можно, надо поменять язык со статической типизацией на язык с динамической. Например на Python.

Comment: Если не указывать тип вообще, то можно.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, например, Integer or String

Comment: @НиколайБеляков можно пример?

Comment: List like = new ArrayList<>(); и можно помещать туда объекты разных типов.

Comment: @НиколайБеляков у меня подчеркивает

Comment: List like = new ArrayList(); Значит без угловых скобочек

Comment: `List<Object> like = new ArrayList<>();` и складывайте туда что хотите

Comment: Мне кажется, или вы совсем не поняли вопроса.

Comment: Смысл заключается в том, чтобы уже созданный объект изменять

Comment: @michael_best в Java - никак.Это можно в том случае есть `Type2` является наследником `Type1` ну или имплементирует `Type1` (если это интерфейс). А если эти типы никак не связаны - то никак.